# Cross platforms decoding

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, dev-groups

To advance those coding language and enhance the combination of gameplay device.

Here are a file extension with ".d"

Any compilers would I find for checking if it's able to run?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Is this "somefile.d" a file that you have created directly, or that has been output as a byproduct of a specific set of steps with a particular tool? Or is it a file you've found / obtained from a third party (who/where)? What does this file represent, and what do you want to do with it? And how does this relate to the game or mod you are making?

Comment: Can you open the file in a text editor? If so, including the contents in your question with an edit would help us identify it. It might be a [Dlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)) source file, but it's impossible to tell without more information.

Comment: Yes! It is a "something.d" file also. And I find there are no suitable compiler to check if it's work or not. In order to edit/recreate my game character by the users self.